# Отключил случайно joomla

Tags: joomla

как устранить эту ошибку на joomla?
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error

Answer (score 1):

В свое время сталкивался с такой ошибкой.
1) Проверьте, есть ли связь с базой данных. Настройки подключения в config.php
2) Проверьте, есть ли у пользователя базы данных нужные привелегии
2) Если в админку зайти можете - очистите кэш страниц Joomla.

**Как отредактировать файл настроек**
1) Открыть файл **configuration.php**, который расположен в той директории, куда вы установили Joomla
2) Найти в нем такие строчки и внести следующие правки:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql';   // Тип базы данных mysql или mysqli
public $host = 'localhost'; // Оставить как есть
public $user = 'user';      // Изменить на 'mysql' или ваше имя пользователя для БД
public $password = 'pass';  // Изменить на 'mysql' или ваше пароль для БД
public $db = 'demo';        // Изменить на имя вашей базы данных
```

**Как еще можно решить проблему**
1) Создать нового пользователя в базе данных и отредактировать файл настроек.
2) Переустановить всю Joomla или перезалить базу данных.

Comment: в том то и дело что я не могу зайти ни в админку, ни на сайт

Comment: Зайдите по ftp и проверьте файл настроек и указанные в нем данные для подключения к БД. Плюс обратитесь к хостеру с описанием проблемы.

Comment: у меня на локальном хостинге, точнее на денвере

Comment: Еще раз говорю, проверьте подключение к базе данных. Соединение устанавливается?

Comment: я не очень понимаю как это делать, могу только сказать что в configuration база подключина

Answer (score 0):

С базой оказалось всё норм а вот пользователя надо было указать

Comment: @Роман Соколов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).